The controller is not available at localhost:9990:
Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available at localhost:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9990. The connection timed out: WFLYPRT0023: Could not connect to remote+http://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
Hi all i am getting this error when running
./jboss-cli.sh --connect
./jboss-cli.sh --connect
it should connect to localhost

You can use --controller=host:port. I think maybe localhost:9999 works? It's for JBoss EAP 6 but WildFly should have its own documentation. See more info by running jboss-cli.sh --help
